# How can I determine $\lim_{x\rightarrow 2} \frac{(x^3-5x^2+8x-4)}{x^4-5x-6}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

This is the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{x^3-5x^2+8x-4}{x^4-5x-6}$$

Thank you.

Comment: Factor numerator and denominator (both have a factor of $x-2$). Then cancel and proceed ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I'm guessing you found out, the numerator and denominator **both** evaluate to $0$ at $x = 2$ $(\dagger)$.  But the **limit** may nonetheless exist as $x$ **approaches** $2$.  so whenever such a situation arises, that indicates *more work needs to be done.*

- In this case, we can apply l'Hospital once, and evaluate, or
- we can note that we have polynomials in each of the numerator and denominator, and it is quite likely that each can be factored, and perhaps, a common factor can be found: Recall the [Rational Root Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem)

Indeed, we can factor and will find both the numerator and denominator share a common, and in fact, it's exactly the a factor that evaluates to $0$ when evaluated at $x = 2:\;$  $(x - 2)$.

$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{x^3-5x^2+8x-4}{x^4-5x-6} = \lim_{x\to 2} \frac{(x - 2)(x^2 - 3x + 2)}{(x - 2)(x^3 + 2x^2 + 4x + 3)} $$

Now we can eliminate the factor (cancel it from the numerator and denominator):
$$\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{(x - 2)(x^2 - 3x + 2)}{(x - 2)(x^3 + 2x^2 + 4x + 3)} = \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x^2 - 3x + 2}{x^3 + 2x^2 + 4x + 3}$$

Can you take it from here?

---

$(\dagger)$ [If it were **only** the denominator that evaluated to zero, but the numerator evaluated to some **non-zero** real value, then the limit would approach either $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ or fail to exist altogether. In this case however, we have what is called an "indeterminate" form: meaning more work needs to be done before "evaluating" the limit.]

Answer (score 0):

Both numerator and denominator approach $0$ as $x\to 2$, so you can use l’Hospital’s rule. However, you can resort to more elementary techniques: $x-2$ must be a factor of both polynomials, so just divide it out:

$$x^3-5x^2+8x-4=(x-2)(x^2-3x+2)\;,$$

and

$$x^4-5x-6=(x-2)(x^3+2x^2+4x+3)\;.$$

It’s not needed, but further factorization is possible in both cases:

$$x^2-3x+2=(x-1)(x-2)\;,$$

and

$$x^3+2x^2+4x+3=(x+1)(x^2+x+3)\;.$$

These factorizations are easily found using the [rational root test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are dealing with a limit that approaches to a number so that the denominator ends up being 0, the first thing you want to try is to see if the denominator and the numerator have anything in common. This is the case which does that.

Now, it is not clear right away that $x-2$ is a factor of both the numerator and the denominator, but because of what I said above, we can see if it does.

Assuming that you know how to do long or synthetic division, you can find out that

$$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x^3-5x^2+8x-4}{x^4-5x-6} = \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{(x-2)(x^2-3x+2)}{(x-2)(x^3+2x^2+4x+3)}$$

So the term $(x-2)$ will divide each other out.

If you try to plug in $x=2$ again, there is no problem because the denominator is not 0 anymore.

Now, geometrically speaking you also want to know what's going on. In this problem, there is a "hole" as $x \to 2$. Even though the function is not defined at $2$, the graph keeps approaching to that number.

Does this help ?